# jquery delete value from array if contains a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with the google maps API and what I want to do is use jQuery as a filter to remove locations from its location data

so if the user clicks filter english then jquery would look for entries that do not contain English in them, then once it finds them it would remove the [ ] along with its content.

```
var LocationData = [
[-33.911187337771345,18.41437339782715,"&lt;a class=english href=http://lang.beresponsive.net/blog/2013/09/10/hello-world/&gt;Hello world!&lt;/a&gt;","http://lang.beresponsive.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Logo.png"],
[-33.95902344617683,18.481578826904297,"&lt;a class=french href=http://lang.beresponsive.net/blog/2012/07/30/cu-vel-suas-interpretaris-no-qui-tantas-2/&gt;Lightbox Image&lt;/a&gt;","http://lang.beresponsive.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Logo.png"],
 ];
```

I was thinking something like

```
jQuery('.filter-eng').click(function(){
  //not sure what would go here to preform this. 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with jQuery grep() method.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

```
var NewLocationData = $.grep(LocationData, function(val) { 
  return val[1].indexOf("english") === -1; 
});
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example, that is only working with text in the jquery example im trying to remove based on a text within the array

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
for (x in LocationData) {
     $.grep(x, function(value) {
           return value.match("class=english") != null;
           },
           true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is what you want for your given example.

```
var result = $.grep(LocationData, function(location) {
    return /english/i.test(location[2]);
});
```